# How do i write build-main.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I am new with the ant concept. I want to write the build-main.xml  for the  project which also include two other projects.

Just check the image.

[image]
how to write build for the main project ant-utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get elements from [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-up-multiple-projects-to-share-the-same-ant-targets.html?page=1)